# MSI Error 1612 during uninstallation

Tags: windows, installation, sccm, msi

I was trying to uninstall one application from SCCM. This application was installed about 4 years ago.
I used uninstall option in application based deployment. However, it was failed with error 1612.
Again i tried to use the package based uninstallation. It is also failed with 1612.
I did some research and created a script to perform the uninstallation.

The script will update the registry key.

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{J124B8513-EA8C-46A1-9735-XXXXXX}

And then it will place the msi file at that path. After that uninstallation will start.

Script works fine locally but when i run it from sccm it didn't removed the application. rest all steps works fine.

```
@echo off
REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{J124B8513-EA8C-46A1-9735-xxxxxx}" /V InstallSource /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{J124B8513-EA8C-46A1-9735-xxxxxx}" /V InstallSource /t REG_SZ /d c:\temp\LMi /f

md "c:\temp\LMi" /f
copy "%~dp0App.msi" "c:\temp\LMi\" /y

MsiExec.exe /X {J124B8513-EA8C-46A1-9735-xxxxxx} /q REBOOT=ReallySuppress
```

I am out of solution now. If i manually install the application and uninstall it then it is working fine but not sure on actual devices why it is giving 1612 error.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are the batch file and the MSI file in the same folder?

Comment: @duenni yes they are in same folder.

Comment: As you have the correct msi did you try uninstalling with /x <path to msi> instead of the guid? It should be possible. Also it might give insight to use the logging features of msiexec (although 1612 is a pretty obvious error). Third idea: if this is a program not an application remove the WOW6432Node from the regpath in the script, sccm programs are executed in 32bit and will be wow redirected automatically (also maybe check if the key is set correctly after the sccm prog ran or if it is in WOW6432Node\WOW6432Node instead)